# Is there any drawback of using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem in web app.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I did some research on this topic, but I am unable to find the expected answer for this. In my application I have used

> ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Like following way.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => CaseBll.SendEmailNotificationForCaseUpdate(currentCase, caseUpdate));
```

My app in asp.net mvc & I have handled all background task which is not required to execute on user operation for faster execution & quick user response. 
Now I wants to know that, Is there any bad side of using **ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem** When we have larger audience for application.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should never use it. I can write a lot of reasons why but instead you should read this article from Scott Hansleman who is a genius IMHO

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChecklistWhatNOTToDoInASPNET.aspx

Under "Reliability and Performance":

> Fire-and-Forget Work - Avoid using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem as your app pool could disappear at any time. Move this work outside or use WebBackgrounder if you must.

So, as recommended, don't use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem. An excellent alternative for this is at:

https://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet-and-what-to-do-instead#fire

Edit: As mentioned by @Scott-Chamberlain, here's a better link:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: Here is a better more updated blog post specifically on doing background work in ASP.net: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: I would not say you "should never use it". Only Sith Lords deal in absolutes... :-) There are scenarios where it makes sense to use this class.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are going to be doing but generally speaking, your likely concerns will be:

- Persistence. Threads in the managed pool are background threads. They will die when the application recycles which is generally undesirable. In your case you want to send e-mails. Imagine if your process dies for some reason before the thread executes. Your e-mail will never be sent.
- Local storage is shared, which means you need to make sure there are no leftovers from the last thread if using it. Applies to fields marked with ThreadStaticAttribute as well.

I would instead recommend that you implement a job scheme where you schedule the job somewhere and have some other component actually read from this list (e.g. database) and perform the job, then mark it as complete. That way it persists across application unload, there is no memory reuse and you can throttle the performance. You could implement the processing component inside your application or even as a Windows service if you prefer.